# What is the standard size of a desk calendar?

Tags: print-design, dimensions

I have a new task to design a desk calendar. I've never designed a calendar so far. Can someone help me with the standard dimensions and resolution of a desk calendar.

Edit:
this is actually for a corporate.

Comment: ...ask your printer of choice?

Comment: Hi Yaalan, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: If it's a Gregorian calendar, it should begin on January 1, go all the way through the summer, and stop on December 31.

Comment: +1 It's normally best to ask your printer, but sometimes that's not possible (e.g. I've had clients who use outsourcing firms for printing, where you have to send artwork to them "blind" then the outsourcing firm rings around and negotiates with different printers, meaning you don't get specs until the last possible minute... ugh!), so it's good to know "typical" dimensions. Browsing big-name print firms is a good way to start, but hopefully this'll get an experience-based answer!

Comment: @LaurenIpsum :) lol...

Comment: This question has some problems: 1) What do you mean by "desk calendar"? There are different types. Some lie flat, some stand up. 2) This question assumes there is a "standard," but there likely isn't. 3) What effort have you put into finding the answer on your own? Why aren't those efforts working?

Comment: @LaurenIpsum .. but... but... February always messes up the size! Seems like there's a pattern to it, but I can't quite figure it out.

Comment: @Scott You always design for the worst-case scenario. More than half of the months have 31 days, so design for that. A little white space around the shorter months is okay; it lets the calendar breathe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find many different samples of table calendar on the link below.

The budget of your client for the printing fees may be the most important factor in your choice of size and style. Some calendars are more expensive because they are bigger or require a special binding and are harder to assemble. If you have the full freedom on this, look at the link below and choose what you prefer! You can also create your own custom size in that case; printers will print what you give them since there is no "template" or diecut for calendars. But I still recommend you contact the printer to make sure your dimensions are alright (especially the base of the calendar, it needs to be stable!)

For you as a designer, you'll need to be careful in the way you will create the calendar; not only you need to create the pages but you might also need to create the "base" of the calendar if it's a printed one. Some calendars that have sheets that are fully covering the base may not require a design for the base since it won't be visible. And these calendars are usually cheaper to print as well and the most standard ones. But it can be printed as well, it's really a question of preference and budget. **So when you ask for the size of the calendar pages, you also need to not forget about the size of the base of the calendar!**

The resolution of your images should always be 300dpi and up.

Create all the texts and icons in vector as much as possible for a clear and sharp printing. This is very important.

Be careful to leave some room for the spiral binding on top of the calendar. Usually, 0.5 - 0.625 inch is good enough. You can put color and elements in that part but don't put your text too close to the spiral.

http://www.calendarcustom.ca/desktop_calendars.php

====

And if I may add 2 suggestions...

It's good to add the month of january of the next year. The clients of your client who use the calendar will enjoy being able to note down appointments or special events on the january month when they're still in december. People often prefer to change calendar in january after they come back from their vacations and adding the extra january month can be very practical for them since they won't need to use 2 calendars in december! It may look like a detail but if it makes the calendar more practical to them, they will use it over another company's calendar... and that's the whole point of giving a calendar to clients!

I created a lot of calendars and usually people love having nice big squares or lot of room for each day of the month; they like to have enough room to note down some stuff on the calendar. Maybe it's less stylish than using numbers only but again, it's very practical!